# Do exist a workaround to the visibility:collapse Chrome incompatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, visibility

I need to make disappear the thead duplicate of this table, without losing the width and height properties. The

```
visibility: collapse
```

property would do the work perfectly. But in Chrome doesn't seem to work.

Here is a example:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/meT7k/)

This above, work properly in firefox, but it is interpreted like a *:hidden* in Chrome.

I need to achieve the same result in chrome, for this table:

[JSFIDDLE MY TABLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ciaoben/aVT7W/266/)

Comment: Use `display: none;` instead.

Comment: `display:none` doesn't allow me to calculate the height and the width for the cloned header

Comment: Ah, my bad. I should really learn to fully read the question!

Comment: no problems, thanks anyway